# NativeAppEventEmitter returns undefined

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, react-native

I have been trying to get a hold of a logged in user access token for quite a while. I had major issues with it in JS so I tried and succeeded in Obj-C.

After that I went through this guide on RN: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#sending-events-to-javascript on how to pass a string from Obj-C to JS, and it seemt to have been successfull. However, the thing is that it returns undefined, and that pisses me off because it calls on the string and I can see how my Obj-C returns it properly in the log, but when its supposed to be logged by my JS after login, it is undefined.

In AppDelegate.m I have this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
  BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                                openURL:url
                                                      sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                             annotation:annotation
                  ];

  NSString *fbAccessToken = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString;

  [self.bridge.eventDispatcher sendAppEventWithName:@"AccessToken"
                                               body:@{@"name": fbAccessToken}];

  NSLog(@"%@", fbAccessToken);

  return handled;
}
```

Which logs successfully a working accesstoken. In JS I invoke the EventEmitter by: `var subscription = NativeAppEventEmitter.addListener('AccessToken');`, which should work I guess since I also looked at this example: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Geolocation/Geolocation.js, where they have done it seemingly exactly like me.

To simply call the subscriber gives me this:

```
2016-05-06 10:39:31.013 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] { subscriber: 
   { _subscriptionsForType: 
      { AccessToken: 
         [ { subscriber: [Circular],
             listener: undefined,
             context: undefined,
             eventType: 'AccessToken',
             key: 0 },
           [Circular] ] },
     _currentSubscription: null },
  listener: undefined,
  context: undefined,
  eventType: 'AccessToken',
  key: 1 }
```

So calling name or body gives me only `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have to catch incoming data so try something like this (this was in the docs example!):

```
var subscription = NativeAppEventEmitter.addListener(
 'AccessToken',
 (token) => console.log(token.name)
);
```

Remember that you can't really call `subscriber` directly.

Comment: Now is sais under Listener: [function] instead of undefined. But how can I call this so I can get the string from Obj-c?

Comment: You can't really call this. `NativeAppEventEmitter` sends an event from objc to JS. You can't use it in a different way. The token will be sent when it is dispatched from objc.

Comment: Does this mean that the string I generated in ObjC is useless for my operations in JS?

Comment: It's not useless. It will be available only when the event is sent (you can't get it manually). Then you can save it and use in JS.

Comment: Ok, but that has been my main issue all along, how can I save it in JS going from here? Where is it stored when I call the EventEmitter?

Comment: You can do anything with it (save to a state - check react state in Google). In the last line of my answer you can call a method that save the data `(token) => this.saveMyToken(token.name)` or `(token) => this.setState({token: token.name})` to set state. If you want to store more data the read about redux.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111224/discussion-between-niklas-lindeke-and-radek-czemerys).